# retrieve data for current user only in DRF

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-filters

I was wondering how can I limit the queryset to the data associated with the current user. Here is my view:

```
class TradingGroupList(generics.ListAPIView):
        queryset = Tradegroup.objects.all()
        serializer_class = TradeGroupSerializer
        name = 'tradegroup-list'
```

I would write somethinng like `queryset = Tradegroup.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)` in native django, but was wondering how I could achieve this here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should actually work by overriding the get_queryset method. Simply add this method to your ListAPIView and it should work.

```
class TradingGroupList(generics.ListAPIView):
    
    serializer_class = TradeGroupSerializer
    name = 'tradegroup-list'

    def get_queryset(self)
        return Tradegroup.objects.all().filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

I hope this works for you. If you have a problem with it just give me a comment.